# JavaFX Shape.intersect() performance issue

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, collision-detection, javafx-8

I have start writing a shooting game JavaFX application. I am using Shape.intersect() to check the collision of bullet and the target. Below is my code and I made it simple so as to post here.

```
public class TestShapeIntersect extends Application{
 AnchorPane anchorPane;      
 ArrayList<Rectangle> targetObjects;
public static void main(String[] arg){
    launch(arg);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final Rectangle gun = new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.RED);
    anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
    anchorPane.getChildren().add(gun);  
    generateTargetObjects(50); // Number of target objects
    anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(targetObjects);
    gun.setX(50);
    gun.setY(200);
    Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane,300,300,Color.GREEN);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            Rectangle bullet = new Rectangle(5,10,Color.ORANGE);
            bullet.setX(75);
            bullet.setY(200);
            anchorPane.getChildren().add(bullet);
            animateBullet(bullet);

        }
    });             
}

private void generateTargetObjects(int noOfTargetObj) {
    targetObjects = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    for(int i=1; i<=noOfTargetObj;i++){
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(30, 30, Color.YELLOW);
        targetObjects.add(rect);        
    }       
}

 void animateBullet(final Rectangle bullet){
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.setCycleCount(500);
        final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(2), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                bullet.setY(bullet.getY()-1);               
                checkCollision(bullet);
            }       
        });    
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);        
        timeline.play();
}

 //This method will check if there is any collision happened between the bullets and the targets.
 //If collision happens then both bullet and target object will be disappeared.
 void checkCollision(Rectangle bullet){
     int noOfTargetObjs = targetObjects.size();

        for(int i=0; i<noOfTargetObjs;i++)
        {
            if(targetObjects.get(i).isVisible()==true && bullet.isVisible()==true){
                Shape intersectShape= Shape.intersect(bullet, targetObjects.get(i));
                if(intersectShape.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1){                 
                    targetObjects.get(i).setVisible(false);
                    bullet.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }    
 }
}
```

I have not yet aligned the nodes properly.Here the 'gun' rectangle will fire 'bullet' rectangle whenever any key press event is detected.

The problem is for every every first bullet fired in each application session, the very first bullet is not animated properly (means the bullet is not going in it path continuously). But after the first bullet has gone the remaining bullets are animated properly. This performance issue increases with the number of 'target' objects increases.

I have found out that the issue is because of this line:

```
    Shape intersectShape= Shape.intersect(bullet, targetObjects.get(i));
```

Could anyone let me know why this happens and what could be the solution to resolve this issue? Or is it because of the way that I'm implementing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're sending way too many requests to Shape.intersect(...), which is probably a fairly expensive method to execute. Initially this is causing performance problems, but when the number of calls to the method hits some threshold, the JVM's JIT compiler kicks in and compiles that method, relieving some of the problems. (Again, this is all guesswork.)

Using a TranslateTransition for the bullet and listening to its boundsInParent property to check for collisions seems to work better. I think the reason is that using this technique only checks for collisions when the JavaFX machinery actually moves the bullet. In your code you are performing these checks much more often.

[Here's an example.](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8149902)

Comment: Good thinking with the Listener on the boundsInParent property.

Comment: So you mean to say that using Timeline transition it is hard to implement such application. But I think most of the animation games seems to use Timelines only.

Comment: A TranslateTransition is just a special case of a Timeline. You could use a Timeline here, but the code would be slightly more complex as TranslateTransitions are specifically designed for this kind of animation. But in either case, I would observe the boundsInParent property to detect collisions.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced a different behaviour when i executed your application. My first shot was moving fine without any interruptions in the translation. But after several shots the application began to slow down. I tried to improve the performance of your code by doing the following steps:

```
void animateBullet(final Rectangle bullet){
       final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
       timeline.setCycleCount(125); //changed
       final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(16), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

           @Override
           public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
               bullet.setY(bullet.getY()-8);     //changed          
               checkCollisionThreaded(bullet); //changed
               //added
               if(bullet.getX() < 0 || bullet.getX() > bullet.getParent().getBoundsInParent().getWidth()
               || bullet.getY() < 0 || bullet.getY() > bullet.getParent().getBoundsInParent().getHeight())
               {
                   bullet.setVisible(false);
                   timeline.stop();
                   AnchorPane ap = (AnchorPane) bullet.getParent();
                   ap.getChildren().remove(bullet);

               }
           }       
       });    
       timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf); 
       timeline.play();
}
```

Your value for the `Duration.millis` factor in the `KeyFrame` was 2, which is not really necessary to run a fluent animation, because JavaFX has a fixed framerate of 60 frame per second, which means that every 16,7 milliseconds a new frame is rendered and displayed. So you can use 16ms as frame-duration without making the animation stutter.

The if-statement checks if the bullet is outside the visible screen, which could happen in your previous code. Non-visible nodes should be removed from the scene graph. It doesn't help if you set a node to `setVisible(false)`, because the node will stay on the scene graph. The `Timeline` animation should also be stopped, because it would trigger new `checkCollision` calls. As you can see, i changed the method `checkCollision` to `checkCollisionThreaded`. The method is shown below.

```
 public void checkCollisionThreaded(final Rectangle bullet)
{
    final int noOfTargetObjs = targetObjects.size();       
    Task<Integer> t = new Task<Integer>()
    {

        @Override
        protected Integer call() throws Exception
        {
            for(int i=0; i<noOfTargetObjs;i++)
            {
                if(targetObjects.get(i).isVisible()==true && bullet.isVisible()==true){
                    Shape intersectShape= Shape.intersect(bullet, targetObjects.get(i));
                    if(intersectShape.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1){
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }    
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded()
        {
            super.succeeded();
            if(this.getValue().intValue() != -1)
            {
              Node obj = targetObjects.get(this.getValue().intValue());
              obj.setVisible(false);
              AnchorPane ap = (AnchorPane) obj.getParent();
              ap.getChildren().remove(obj);              
              targetObjects.remove(this.getValue().intValue());

              bullet.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(t);
    thread.start();
}
```

There are some violations against the rule "don't touch any objects on the scene graph with a thread different to the JavaFX application thread", but as far as i can see, only reading methods access the scene graph (and it's objects) in the `call()` method. This method is run on a new `Thread`, which improves performance. The method `succeeded()` is run on the JavaFX Application Thread, so that we can safely remove things from our scene graph. I assumed that you want to remove your targets from the scene once they were hit.

It should be said that there might be issues related to the multithreaded code. There could be errors when getting `final int noOfTargetObjs = targetObjects.size();` while modifying it on another thread. I left out any synchronization to reduce the complexity of the code.

Comment: Reading properties of Nodes that are part of a live scene graph is only allowed on the JavaFX Application thread. There is no guarantee that your code will give the correct results. I don't think you can fix this by synchronization, as the scene graph itself assumes single-threaded access.

Comment: Yes you are of course right. I should have mentioned that a bit better in my answer. The synchronization part was meant for the `ArrayList` `targetObjects` and its size.

Comment: @denhackl, I am new to javafx and I am not aware of javaFX threading. As of now your code is working properly, but after reading the last part of your description and the comments,I feel that this solution may not be efficient. Could you please provide some links where I can find the JavaFX threading concept for the one that you mentioned above: "don't touch any objects on the scene graph with a thread different to the JavaFX application thread".